# Why doesn't the window set cursor correctly?

Tags: c, winapi, cursor

As [MSDN describes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153552.aspx):

> When the mouse moves over a window, the window receives a `WM_SETCURSOR` message (unless another window has captured the mouse).
>
> If the application passes `WM_SETCURSOR` to `DefWindowProc`, the `DefWindowProc` function uses the following algorithm to set the cursor image:
>
> 1. If the window has a parent, forward the `WM_SETCURSOR` message to the parent to handle.
> 2. Otherwise, if the window has a class cursor, set the cursor to the class cursor.
> 3. If there is no class cursor, set the cursor to the arrow cursor.

And here's my source code:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInsTance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };
  HWND hWnd;
  BOOL ret;
  MSG msg;

  wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
  wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
  wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  // wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wcex.lpszClassName = TEXT("MainWindow");
  wcex.hIconSm = wcex.hIcon;

  RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
  hWnd = CreateWindow(wcex.lpszClassName, TEXT("Test"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

  ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hWnd);

  while (ret = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    if (ret == -1)
    {
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
  }
  return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (uMsg)
  {
  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    break;
  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I move my cursor quickly over the window, the cursor doesn't change to an arrow, it become a resize arrow; if I set `wcex.hCursor` to `LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW)`, everything will be all right. My question is: why doesn't my code work as MSDN says?

I mean, if I don't set `wcex.hCursor`, and I don't handle the `WM_SETCURSOR` message, the `DefWindowProc` should "set the cursor to the arrow cursor", but it seems it doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: I repro.  That article is just wrong, go by what the docs for WM_SETCURSOR tells you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See description of the `hCursor` member of the `WNDCLASSEX`:

> A handle to the class cursor. This member must be a handle to a cursor
>   resource. If this member is NULL, an application must explicitly set
>   the cursor shape whenever the mouse moves into the application's
>   window.

[WNDCLASSEX structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @EFanZh in other words you must handle WM_CURSOR in you event loop.

Comment: Then why MSDN says the `DefWindowProc` will act as "If there is no class cursor, set the cursor to the arrow cursor."?

Comment: @EFanZh I don't know. It is apparently a mistake in the tutorial, which is not an official API documentation.